Как в сниппете правильно записать параметр
Пытаюсь создать сниппет. В одной из строк есть параметр для номера телефона pattern="+?[0-9\s-()]+".
Как правильно записать ее корректно в сниппет чтобы она в дальнейшем при вызове сниппета выводилась корректно
"fieldset-div": {
        // "scope": "html",
        "prefix": "fieldset-div+",
        "body": [
            "<fieldset class=\"\">\n\t\n<legend class=\"\"></legend>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"text\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"First name\" required>\n\t</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"text\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"First name\" required>\n\t</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"tel\" name=\"\" pattern="\+?[0-9\s\-\(\)]+" placeholder=\"Phone number\">\n\t</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"email\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"Email address\" required>\n\t</div>\n\t\n</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<textarea id=\"\" class=\"\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"Message\" autocomplete=\"off\"></textarea>\n\t</div>\n\t\n</fieldset>"
        ],
        "description": "Структура в HTML fieldset-div-input"
    },




Точно так же, как и другие параметры, прям на вашем скриншоте прекрасно видно как их правильно записывать...

Не выходит. Если не затруднит могли бы продемонстрировать

В приведенном коде кавычки экранируются во всех атрибутах кроме pattern. Нужно сделать однообразно все. Кроме того, обратный слэш - это специальный символ и его нужно экранировать так же как и кавычки

@MoloF, а как тут это поможет?

Проблема заключается в том, что внутри JSON-сниппета кавычки (") используются для обозначения строк
Чтобы избежать этой ошибки, нужно экранировать кавычки внутри строки, используя обратный слэш ().
"fieldset-div": {
    "prefix": "fieldset-div+",
    "body": [
        "<fieldset class=\"\">\n\t\n<legend class=\"\"></legend>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"text\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"First name\" required>\n\t</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"text\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"First name\" required>\n\t</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"tel\" name=\"\" pattern=\"\\+?[0-9\\s\\-\\(\\)]+\" placeholder=\"Phone number\">\n\t</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<input id=\"\" class=\"\" type=\"email\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"Email address\" required>\n\t</div>\n\t\n</div>\n\t\n<div class=\"\">\n\t<textarea id=\"\" class=\"\" name=\"\" placeholder=\"Message\" autocomplete=\"off\"></textarea>\n\t</div>\n\t\n</fieldset>"
    ],
    "description": "Структура в HTML fieldset-div-input"
}

